# AngularJS how to check multiple http request done and do something after all response done

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i'm sending HTTP request through for loop, i want to know how can i do something after all response came.

This is my code.

```
$scope.totalIdSet = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23...ect] total id count will be  more than 200

for (var k = 0; k < $scope.totalIdSet.length; k++) {

MydocumentsServices.downloadDoc($scope.totalIdSet[k], $scope.loggedUserInfo.access_token).then(function (res) {

                }, function () {

                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do create collection of promise array of your `httpRequests`. For the same you have to return promise from `downloadDoc` method. So over here you can use `$q.all` which would wait until all promises accomplish.

**Service**

```
function downloadDoc (totalIdSet, access_token) {
   return $http.post('someurl', totalIdSet, {headers: {Authorization: access_token}})
}
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.totalIdSet = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
var promises = []
for (var k = 0; k < $scope.totalIdSet.length; k++) {
    var promise = MydocumentsServices.downloadDoc($scope.totalIdSet[k], $scope.loggedUserInfo.access_token)
    promises.push(promise)
}
$q.all(promises).then(function(responses) {
  console.log(responses)

}, function() {

});
```

Comment: this is not a good solution reason being if any HTTP call fails then the complete promise.all will throw a error

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) in order to run asynchronous functions and wait for their responses and do what you want after that.

For example,

```
$q.all(arrayOfHttpFunctions).then(responses => {
    // Do your thing here
})
```

where `arrayOfHttpFunctions` is an array of $http request object.